# How to remove the LAST set Parentheses from a Excel text string that contains only numeric s

Tags: excel, vba, parentheses

I have an excel spreadsheet with over 50,000 entries. The entries have a name and address and sometimes a phone number ALL in the same string. I am concentrating on the phone number part of the string which is always at the end and enclosed in parentheses. I have been trying to use VBA code to address this.
How to remove the LAST set Parentheses from a Excel text string that contains only numeric s between the parentheses. In any given string there may be either NO parentheses or multiple parentheses but I only want to remove that LAST set and leave the numbers contained there in the string

Example string "Toone Carkeet J., agt.,Alliance Assurance Co. Ltd.  (Provident Life branch), 3 St. Andrew st. (1936)" I have tried using `VBScript.RegExp` to define "(1936)" but I cannot get the `RegExp` to match the string and replace the parentheses () with "".

```
For Each Cell In Range
    If strPattern<> "" Then
        strInput = Cell
        With regEx
            .Pattern="\(([0-9]))*)"
            .Global=False
        End With
        If .Pattern= True Then
            Replace(Cell.Value, "(","")
        End If
```

Comment: To use your algorithm, you could use the `.Test` method.  But `Replace` won't `Replace` if it doesn't match, so testing is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two quick user defined functions that do not rely on regular expressions. The first uses VBA's StrReverse and the second InStrRev.

```
Function RemoveParens1(str As String)

    str = StrReverse(str)

    str = Replace(str, "(", vbNullString, 1, 1)
    str = Replace(str, ")", vbNullString, 1, 1)

    RemoveParens1 = StrReverse(str)

End Function

Function RemoveParens2(str As String)

    Dim o As Integer, c As Integer

    o = InStrRev(str, "(")
    c = InStrRev(str, ")")

    str = Left(str, c - 1) & Mid(str, c + 1)
    str = Left(str, o - 1) & Mid(str, o + 1)

    RemoveParens2 = str

End Function
```

If you don't want to use UDFs, just pick the logic method you prefer and adapt it for your own purposes.

Here's one more using regular expression's Replace.

```
Function RemoveParens3(str As String)

    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object, tmp As String

    If rgx Is Nothing Then Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\([0-9]*\)"

        If .test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            tmp = cmat.Item(cmat.Count - 1)
            tmp = Mid(tmp, 2, Len(tmp) - 2)
            str = .Replace(str, tmp)
        End If
    End With

    RemoveParens3 = str

End Function
```

Comment: Nice effort, plus 1.

Comment: User11450033 Thank you for the speedy result. Of the 3 Functions the third is the best because it extracts to Cell "Bxxx" just the numbers inside the Parentheses. I appreciate your work on my behalf. However, I would prefer to use a VBA Sub  in the module so that the original string is updated. I am new to this site so am finding my feet so to speak. As for VBA I am a complete novice but keen to learn and adapt. Thanks again for your very useful inputs

Comment: User11450033 Just a quick question: I entered the formula in cell "Bxx" and added the cell Number in parentheses to reference the correct cell. Is that the correct way to use the Function? I am new to VBA and new to this site so maybe a little dumb!

Comment: To use this in a sub it could be as easy as `range("A1") = RemoveParens3(range("A1").Text)`. Pu in a loop, you could work through a column of similar string values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using similar logic to yours.
I changed the names of the range variables as it is not a good idea to use keywords for named variables, even if the editor will allow that.

Instead of just deleting the parentheses, we match the entire `(nnnn)` substring with the numbers inside a capturing group, and then replace that match with just the captured group.

Since Replace won't do anything if there is no match, there is no need to test.

Also, note that we set up the regEx OUTSIDE the loop.

```
With regEx
    .Pattern = "\((\d+)\)"
    .Global = False
End With

For Each myCell In myRange
    myCell = regEx.Replace(myCell, "$1")
Next myCell
```

If necessary due to other substrings with the same pattern, you could change the pattern to ensure the match is at the end of the line, or that it is the last pattern of that type in the string.

For example:

- Substring at end of the line

---

```
\((\d+)\)$
```

- Substring the last one

---

```
\((\d+)\)(?!.*\(\d+\))
```

And there may be other modifications necessary if your string is in multiple lines within the cell.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld Nice one, your code worked a treat. Question: setting the regEx outside the Loop causes what safe-guards? Improve performance? Standard practice? - I am new to VBA so it will be good to more fully understand good practices. Thank you very much for your assistance it is much appreciated

Comment: @DJP2019 If you create the regex object inside the loop, you will be creating a new object each time through the loop -- 50,000 regex objects may cause a problem.  Seems more efficient to just create a single object, and reuse it each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x, y, z As Long
x = 2 'ASSUMING YOUR DATA START AT RANGE A2
With Sheet1
Do While .Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
    If Right(.Cells(x, 1).Value, 1) = ")" Then
        .Cells(x, 1).Value = Replace(.Cells(x, 1).Value, ")", "")
        z = VBA.Len(.Cells(x, 1).Value)
        For y = z To 1 Step -1
            If Mid(.Cells(x, 1).Value, y, 1) = "(" Then
                .Cells(x, 1).Value = Replace(.Cells(x, 1).Value, "(", "")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next y

        x = x + 1
    End If
Loop
End With
```

Comment: Joel Thank you for your input it is much appreciated